# How to create rowversion field with using frame work migrations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, rowversion

How would I generate a rowversion field using entity framework migrations?
Here is a sample of what I am trying to achieve.

```
CreateTable(
                companiesTable,
                companies => new
                {
                    Id = companies.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    RowVersion = companies.????,
                    Name = companies.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                    Slug = companies.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256)
                })
                .PrimaryKey(x => x.Id)
                .Index(x => x.Slug, unique: true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Version = c.Binary(nullable: false, fixedLength: true, timestamp: true, storeType: "rowversion"),
```